# stop requests for index.php+++++++++

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am trying to redirect users requesting a root index.php
I was using `Redirect 301 /index.php http://mywebsite/junk/index.html`
while this works ok IF people only request index.php, 
but now i am getting many requests
for index.php++++ (sometimes more ++ than others)

 is there something I can add to `Redirect 301 /index.php` to include redirecting index.php+++  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `mod_rewrite` for regex capabilities and finer control:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index\.php http://mywebsite/junk/index.html [L,R]
```

Comment: is there a way to do it without a error 404 getting generated ?